# How can I ensure that my first animation completes before starting another animation using Framer Motion?

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, css-transitions, framer-motion

I have a div and inside that div I am mapping an array to show list of navlinks inside "p" tag. Each navlink has its own animation,  and parent div has its own animation. I basically have two questions in this thread:

1. As you can see in sandbox that my navlinks are animating, I want same type of animation for navlinks in reverse order when exiting. How can I do so?
2. Navlinks should not start their animation until parent div has completed its animation and same should happen in reverse order when exiting animations - first navlinks should complete their animation and then main div should start its navigation. how to do so?

Here is a link to my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-ace-0sexjm?file=/src/App.js